# How can I get the name of the active c project in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have two projects in eclipse: a C project with C class (named for example hello.c) and a plugin project. I'm trying to add command menu to my plugin eclipse. My question is when I run my plugin, I need to execute the c application (hello.c) , so how Can I know or get access to the name of my C class.

in my handler.java, I have this function "Process process = runTime.exec("/home/eclipse-workspacee/application/Debug/application"); to execute my active c application when I run command menu, but I don't want to use the path to execute the C application, I want to use a function in my handler which executes the C application without path.

THank you in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to access things in a Command Handler? Do you want the name of the current selection? You need to be much more precise about exactly where your code is running and exactly what you want to get. Eclipse has lots of APIs for getting information about files and projects - which ones you use depend of exactly what you are doing.

Comment: in my handler.java, I have this function "Process process = runTime.exec("/home/eclipse-workspacee/application/Debug/application"); to execute my c application when I run command menu, but I don't want to use the path to execute the C application, I want to use a function in my handler java which executes the C application without path. it's clear now?

Comment: When you run your plug-in Eclipse uses a completely separate test workspace which won't contain your C program (unless you have copied it there). The Eclipse APIs can only tell you about things in the test workspace, it can't tell you about projects in your development workspace. You can use The FileLocator API to find things in plug-ins - but only in plug-ins.